# Cannot deploy Cloud Functions because of stripe config variable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am in the middle of integrating stripe in my cloud functions. I use the following code:

```
// CODE CAUSING THE ERROR

const {Stripe} = require('stripe');
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.secret,{
   apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
});
```

I get

> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: (all functions get listed below this)

Before this I did saved my test key in config variables with the following command:

> firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret="MY STRIPE KEY"
> firebase deploy --only functions

So when I run `firebase functions:config:get` I do get to see my key as below:

```
{
  "stripe": {
    "secret": "MY STRIPE KEY"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but I was not able to get any error, update your firebase CLI `sudo npm install -g firebase`,check the [GCP logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and check if something is failing, in my case I tested with this line `console.log(functions.config().stripe.secret)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just moved the .runtimeconfig.json into the functions folder like is explained here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/264